# Common ground with 9V?

Tags: gpio, power-supply, electronics

I'm new to pi's extending.

I've a [MB102 breadboard, coupled with a powersupply](http://artofcircuits.com/product/mb102-breadboard-power-supply-module-3-3v5v).

I plugged a 9V power supply, and it's working (powersupply => resistor => led on).

I'd like to interface some components using the Pi's GPIO.

Because there would be two generators (the pi and the external power supply), how should I cable it ?

I hesitate to connect pi's and powersupply ground together, because I'm not sure how electrical laws apply in this case.

How should I put it all together ?

**[Edit]**: target cabling:

[image]

Comment: This is a good question so I have changed the title to better reflect the central issue (whether it turns out the regulator uses something other than 9V does not make a difference).

Comment: @goldilocks: as I said in my edit, the power supply outputs exactly 3.3V (the actual part I used does not have pwm). 9V are the DC transfo.

Comment: Not sure to understand your PIN remark. http://www.windtopik.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/RPI-GPIO-N-.png. I plugged GND and GPIO15, didn't I?

Comment: BTW it is a bad idea to use gpio 14 and 15 as input/output pins.  They are for UART (serial communication) and you will have to reconfigure them.  Use a pin that does not have a special purpose (eg. gpio 17, 27, 22, 23).  But it still does not make sense with V+ on the other end.

Comment: @goldilocks: In a previous try, I connected the PI's pin like that : +3.3V ==> resistor ==> led ==> GPIO. In this try, I simply replace the pi's 3.3V by the external supply +3.3V. Of you think it's wrong, I may miss something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34831/discussion-between-goldilocks-and-steve-b).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no risk in connecting the GND of the power supply and the RPi together - actually, to create useful circuits most of the time this is required so that the +9V from the power supply and the +5V/+3V3 coming from the Raspberry Pi are relative to each other on the GND.

Regarding the +9V power though, you need to make sure that this does NOT come into contact with the Pi (either directly or via a circuit you're making). It would likely blow up your Pi. What you can do is use a transistor or a relay, powered by the RPi, to switch +9V circuits on your breadboard.

Alternatively, you can just use the power coming from the RPi's GPIO output pins (3V3 signal level) to power simple circuits like those containing a few LEDs, just note that the maximum amperage the RPi can supply that way is 16mA per pin, with a total maximum over all pins of 50mA.

There are tons of good tutorials on the web (try [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com) as an example) on how to start working with circuits on the RPi.

Comment: Thanks, actually, the powersupply has a regulator and can output 3.3 or 5V. If I understand you correctly, is what I put in my edit correct ?

Comment: `to create useful circuits most of the time this is required so that the 9V from the powersupply and the 5V/3V3 coming from the Raspberry Pi are relative to eachother.` can you explain this a bit better please, its very confusing, +9V? -9v, what does relative to each other mean?

Comment: @ppumkin "Relative to" = ground.  You need the common ground if, e.g., the 9V device has 3.3V control logic, or you are using a transistor or relay to interconnect them.

Comment: :) I get it... but the quote makes very little sense. `Relative to each other` - To which other?

Comment: Makes sense to me and I am no electrician. This is exactly the explanation *I needed* when I was confused about this, I think (which was not long ago).  You have 2 voltages, they are *relative to each other*, one is 3.3 and one is 9, the difference is 5.7, but what ensures that exact difference is the common 0 -- ground.  I guess saying that voltage is not an *absolute* value is useful, it is always *relative*.

Comment: I just updated the answer to make it 'absolute'ly clear that relativity is acquired by combining the GND. Also best to mark DC currents and annotations using + or - symbols, since GND is technically -9V as used on technical data sheets. Where 9V is typically interpreted as AC. (I know we have a context of battery here but semantics go a long way in teaching people more while reading in-between the lines)

Comment: Remember that all a 9V battery does it to try to establish a 9 volt _difference_ between its terminals. If you connect its (-) to your system's common ground, then you'd measure its (+) as 9V, but if you connect its (+) to GND, then you'd measure its (-) as -9V. Attach one each way (`(-)Bat1(+)=GND=(-)Bat2(+)`) and you have both +9V and -9V, or attach `GND=(-)Bat1(+)=(-)Bat2(+)` and you have +18V. Voltage _isn't_ a point measurement; it's always the difference between 2 nodes -- when someone talks about the voltage at a node, they're almost always omitting "... relative to the common ground.".